# Modifying dictionary inside function without return statement

Tags: python, function, dictionary, return

I'm trying to modify a dictionary inside a function. And since dictionaries are mutable data types. I was wondering if a return statement is necessary?

e.g:

```
def modify_dict(a_dict,a_key,a_value):
    a_dict = {a_key:a_value}

# Why wouldn't the function actually modify the dictionary? 
# Wouldn't the dictionary still be changed to sample_dict={e_key:e_value} anyways?

sample_dict = {b_key:b_value,c_key:c_value,d_key:d_value}
modify_dict(sample_dict,e_key,e_value)
```

Comment: No, because here you *reassign* `a_dict`, you don't mutate it. Read this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python object variables are *references*.

The assignment operator in python does not work on the values themselves, but on those references.

```py
a = [1,2] # creates object [1,2]
b = [3,4] # creates object [3,4]

# a now holds a reference to [1,2]
# b now holds a reference to [3,4]

c = a

# c now holds a reference to [1,2] as well

c = [5,6] # creates object [5,6]

# c now holds a reference to [5,6] and forgets about the [1,2].
# This does NOT change the [1,2] object.
```

The same applies to your function call:

```py
def modify_dict(a_dict,a_key,a_value):
    # a_dict is a REFERENCE to whatever the argument of the function is

    a_dict = {a_key:a_value} # creates a new dict
    # a_dict now holds a reference to that NEW dict and forgets what it
    # was previously referencing.
    # This does not influence the object that was given as an argument
```

I think the key concept to understand here is that arguments inside functions are *references* to objects, not the objects themselves.

To actually change the a_dict, you need do access it directly instead of assigning to it, like:

```py
def modify_dict(a_dict,a_key,a_value):
    a_dict[a_key] = a_value
```

Answer (score 1):

Your modify dict is not modifying the variable. It is rebinding it.

Try:

```
def modify_dict(a_dict,a_key,a_value):
    a_dict[a_key] = a_value
```

And No.. you don't need to "return".

Answer (score 0):

When you're reassigning `a_dict` inside the function you're actually creating a new dictionary that has the same name as the one outside of the function scope. If you update the dictionary, the change would be visible outside of the function scope, but you're reassigning the name.

Answer (score 0):

While you can modify a dict in place, you're assigning the stack variable `a_dict` to a new dictionary, which is different than changing a value in the dict. You want something more like:

```py
test = {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}
def changes_dict(d, k, new_v):
    d[k] = new_v

changes_dict(test, 'k1', 'changed')
test['k1']
# 'changed'
```